# pyzmq Tornado ioloop: how to handle KeyboardInterrupt gracefully?

Tags: python, pyzmq, keyboardinterrupt

I can catch a KeyboardInterrupt in my pyzmq eventloop:

```
try:
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

But that just stops the ioloop abruptly. I'd like to detect KeyboardInterrupt and shutdown the ioloop manually after a cleanup. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `signal` module to handle `SIGINT`:

```
import signal
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

def on_shutdown():
    print('Shutting down')
    IOLoop.instance().stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ioloop = IOLoop.instance()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda sig, frame: ioloop.add_callback_from_signal(on_shutdown))

    ioloop.start()
```

Comment: aha -- gotit. why can't you call on_shutdown() directly?

Comment: @JasonS: The docs explain the difference: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback_from_signal